# Is SQLite query length on Azure (IIS) limited

Tags: python, sqlite, azure, iis, flask

I am running a flask/python application that uses sqlite3 on IIS windows server.

- When SQL query length is around 2100 bytes or more, the query fails (at fetchall stage).
- When query is artificially shorten (for debug) (<2072), it works.

The query response in both cases should have been the same, so it is not the response size.

IIS http query is set to 4K.

Does IIS limit the sqlite query length? Is there a way to control the limit?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, based on my understanding, I think you created a `flask/python` application as a SQL query client to do the request operation for the SQL statement via HTTP `GET` method, but the default value of `maxQueryString` is 2048, please see the section `Configuration` of the IIS reference page [`Request Limits <requestLimits>`](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits) to know it.

So there are two ways to solve the issue.

1. Using HTTP `POST` method to send the request for querying SQL statements. It's recommended to avoid the request limits.
2. Changing the `maxQueryString` value via follow the above reference page to configure.

Comment: It is not http GET/POST - It is an SQLite query run using cur.execute (query, varList)

Comment: @IritShahar Could you improve your description for more details? As you said, the SQLite query running within `cur.execute` in Python that not be related to IIS. IIS just as a http server to pass http request via wsgi interface for Python.

Comment: When same flask/python application runs on non iis server, everything works fine. In iis however, it gets stuck with error 0x80070102 in fask hansler. The query is invoked from python function to sqlite3. The results are later manipulated to the http (fails before). Query uses "in (?,?..)" format from long lists. When the list is shortened (by user selection in web), the query succeeds. When the list is full (could reach few hundreds) the query fails. The query looks like  cur.execute(query,vart). query=SELECT... WHERE x IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) AND y IN (?,?,?) etc. Var matches a number for every ?

Comment: @IritShahar The error code `0x80070102` seems to be caused by the request handler exceeded configured request timeout, please refer to the [page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx) to try to solve it.

Comment: i think the problem is related with number of variables in query. when it is 59 it works, 92 fails

Comment: @IritShahar I doubt the issue may be caused by the `Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement` (default 1,000,000 bytes) in [Limits In SQLite](http://sqlite.org/limits.html). Please check. If so, you need to redefine the value in the source code of SQLIte and compile by yourself.

Comment: It is not the query length, but the variable list length. In sqlite it should be 999. But 59 works great, 80 works but very slow & 92 (which is what i need) get stuck SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER limits is far above (999)